# PHP Get request has a response of a png, how can i print it?

Tags: php, get

i am using some server's api and i send a get request:

```
 $r = new HttpRequest('https://server.com/chart.png', HttpRequest::METH_GET);
 $r->addQueryData(array('type' => 'graph'));
 $r->addQueryData(array('width' => 900));
 $r->addQueryData(array('height' => 420));
 $r->addQueryData(array('graphid' => 1));
 $r->addQueryData(array('id' => 1234));
 $r->addQueryData(array('username' => 'userName'));
 $r->addQueryData(array('passhash' => 'passHash'));
```

i get a 200 response:

what should i do to print this png?

If i print_r($r) i see:

```
[responseMessage:HttpRequest:private] => HttpMessage Object
    (
        [type:protected] => 2
        [body:protected] => ?PNG

 IHDR?i}?$ IDATx??y?$?}?????????g??Ā    ?H(?C?n??k?i\?K?imP!Ӓ,
 ///and so on....
```

so the image is there, i just dont know how to access it.

Comment: What is `HttpRequest`?  Where are you trying to access it?

Comment: I am trying to send a GET request to a server. i build the Get request with httprequest. sends to server, i get a response as shown in print_r.